# AC/DC 4W vs 2A GSM transmission bursts

Tags: power-supply, cpu, gsm

I have a big problem with the power supply of a SIM900.
I designed my own board with a 220VAC-5VDC tracopower, an ARM9 CPU, and a GSM/GPRS SIM900 module.
The output of the tracopower is 5V - 800 mA (so 4W).
To supply my GSM module, I use a LDO 5V - 4.1V.
When SIM900 is transmitting its 2A burst, 4.1V GSM supply don’t have any voltage drop. But with the 5V supply, I go from 5V to 4.3V, so the CPU reset.

I know that I did a big mistake when I designed the board because I can not supply the CPU directly from the AC/DC. The best solution would have been to use a AC/DC 9V and then create a 5V for the CPU and a 4.1V (from the 9V source) for the GSM. But I can't change the AC/DC so I need to use this AC/DC 5V-800mA.

So do you have a solution to avoid a voltage drop on the 5V ? 
For information, the 4.1V can drop to 3.2 (the Sim900 supports that).

This is my 5V power supply :
[image: 5V Power Supply Schematic]

And this is the GSM power supply :
[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried adding some capacitors on the 4.1V supply of the module? Preferably *after* the inductor.

Comment: How long is the 2A burst for? How long before it happens again (minimum)?

Comment: @AndyAka GSM 2A bursts are 577 µs every 4.6 ms.

Comment: @Damgot I would try adding 2000 µF on the 4.1 rail, just before the GSM module.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the power supply. I think the problem is the interference . You must add capacitor 1microF near your ARM cpu.

Comment: Already done but change nothing. To solve the problem, I've redesigned the board. One AC/DC 12V then one SMPS 4.2V for the GSM and one SMPS 5V for the CPU core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 2A bursts are 577 µs every 4.6 ms

The power for those bursts is equivalent to about 1.25 watts\$^1\$ - if the 4.1V supply were 100% efficient at taking energy from the 5V traco then the power needed would be 1.028 watts but because you are using a linear voltage regulator to create the 4.1 volts then it's 1.25 watts from the traco.

The question is, from your 4 watt traco supply, is the remaining 2.75 watts enough to power the circuits that don't take the 2 A pulse. If it is then that's OK you don't necessarily need to change the traco and you can provide the "surge" power with a large capacitor, preferably directly on the power feeds to the SIM900.

How big? 2 amps at 4.1 volts for 0.577 ms is an energy of 4.73 milli joules so rearranging the well-know energy-capacitance-voltage formula gives you: -

\$C = 2\dfrac{energy}{V^2}= 2\dfrac{4.73 mJ}{16.81}\$ = 563 uF BUT this needs to but at least 5 times bigger so the voltage at the terminals doesn't droop - consider that it needs to be about 3000 uF and use a low ESR type.

---

\$^1\$ average power is 5 volts x 2 amps x 0.577 / 4.6 = 1.25 watts.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried with 5 220µF tantale low ESR on a breadboard but it's not sufficient. So I developped a little board to solder until 20 Low ESR 1500µF electrolytic Capa (EEEFP0J152AP) and connect this little board "as I can" on the 4.1V of my own board. I saw an application note from siemens which says that, for class 10 GPRS, I need between 9400 and 14400 µF Low ESR. So I will test with different values.

Comment: @Damgot did the 1500uF work? How many 20? Seems a lot!!

Comment: I've just ordered my little board today, so I will make my tests next week. 20 is to many, but I desgined my "test" board  for 20 in case I will need it. I think I will need at least 8, according to the Siemens Application note. But capacitance is not the only things, I need to have at least 3A ripple current and ESR not higher than 50 mohm. And 8 EEEFP0J152AP should do it.

Comment: I received my little board and I tried with 8 EEEFP0J152AP and 1 TCJD337M006R0040 so 12330 µF and the result is not so good : http://i.stack.imgur.com/dVgk7.png (Yellow is GSM Supply : 4.3V and Blue is 5V). I don't know what to do to have a better result...

Comment: Can you supply data sheet links to the caps. How much has it improved things? What ESR does the capacitor bank have now?

Comment: For EEEFP0J152AP : http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/370232.pdf. For TCJD337M006R0040 : http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1805435.pdf. The total ESR is now : 0.006 ohm. Now I have a 0.07V voltage drop on GSM Supply and 0.28V Voltage drop on 5V. But I would like to have less than 0.1V voltage drop on 5V

Comment: I think it would be better if you can ask a new (or modify) question with the new circuit - I'm unsure as to what you actually have now and it's a lot easier seeing a circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with [an]other voltage regulator. In my designs I use LP38501 and it works perfectly. [image: +5V to +3.8V,LDO]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain on how your solution takes care of the problems faced by the OP (Eg 4.3v CPU reset )